# Align an image next to a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get to perfectly align a paragraph next to a text but I am struggling, can anyone help? Here is what I have:

```css
#aboutme {
  padding: 50px;
}

#aboutme img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#aboutme p {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: table-cell;
  color: #212529;
}

.intro_link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a69bd;
}

.intro_link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutme">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="./img/face.png">
    <p>Welcome to my personal website! In here, you will find out everything about me. You can scroll down to discover more about my portfolio, my weekly activities or ways to contact me. Before doing so, I shall briefly introduce myself! I am a 20 year
      old student studying at Concordia University in Montreal. Currently, I am in my 2nd year of education pursuing a Bachelors in Software Engineering. Up to now, my experience has been wonderful. I meet great people that share similar interests, my
      network is growing day-by-day and I learn things that interest me. The ultimate goal right now is to graduate and this website will be used to explore everything I learn as I go. For my school assignments and personal projects, you can find them
      in the <a href="#" class="intro_link">portfolio</a> section. If you are ever interested in checking out my other social etworks (GitHub, LinkedIn, etc...) or to contact me, you can go to the <a href="#" class="intro_link">contacts</a> section.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would like to nicely align the paragraph and the image to make it nice and central but I am struggling to understand the properties, I started learning HTML & CSS yesterday

Answer (score 2):

```css
#aboutme{
  padding: 50px;
}

#aboutme img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

/*#aboutme p{
 font-size: 16px;
 display: table-cell;
 color: #212529;
}*/

.intro_link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a69bd;
 }

 .intro_link:hover{
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<section id="aboutme">
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fan-fiction-library/images/1/15/Admin.png/revision/latest?cb=20140917130743">
        <p>Welcome to my personal website! In here, you will find out everything about me. You can scroll down to discover more about my portfolio,
         my weekly activities or ways to contact me. Before doing so, I shall briefly introduce myself! I am a 20 year old student studying at Concordia University in Montreal. Currently, I am in my
          2nd year of education pursuing a Bachelors in Software Engineering. Up to now, my experience
          has been wonderful. I meet great people that share similar interests, my network is growing day-by-day
          and I learn things that interest me. The ultimate goal right now is to graduate and this website will
          be used to explore everything I learn as I go. For my school assignments and personal projects, you can find
          them in the <a href="#" class = "intro_link">portfolio</a> section. If you are ever interested in checking out my other social
          etworks (GitHub, LinkedIn, etc...) or to contact me, you can go to the <a href="#" class = "intro_link">contacts</a> section.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: :-) sometimes we all feel so.. its not our mistake... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex` to achieve this

- Set `display: flex` to `.container`
- Use `align-items: start` in `.container` so that the `image` will not
  get stretched
- Add `margin-right` to `#aboutme img` for spacing between `image` and
  `paragraph`

```css
#aboutme{
  padding: 50px;
}

#aboutme img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#aboutme p{
 font-size: 16px;
 display: table-cell;
 color: #212529;
}

.intro_link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a69bd;
 }

 .intro_link:hover{
    color: red;
 }
 .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutme">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
    <p>Welcome to my personal website! In here, you will find out everything about me. You can scroll down to discover more about my portfolio,
     my weekly activities or ways to contact me. Before doing so, I shall briefly introduce myself! I am a 20 year old student studying at Concordia University in Montreal. Currently, I am in my
      2nd year of education pursuing a Bachelors in Software Engineering. Up to now, my experience
      has been wonderful. I meet great people that share similar interests, my network is growing day-by-day
      and I learn things that interest me. The ultimate goal right now is to graduate and this website will
      be used to explore everything I learn as I go. For my school assignments and personal projects, you can find
      them in the <a href="#" class = "intro_link">portfolio</a> section. If you are ever interested in checking out my other social
      etworks (GitHub, LinkedIn, etc...) or to contact me, you can go to the <a href="#" class = "intro_link">contacts</a> section.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Zuber, I just started to learn HTML so I'm getting a hand of things

Comment: Welcome @Mohanad :) please let me know if you need more clarification. if this answer solved your problem, consider accept it :)